# Seam Solder @MessageBundle generating the implementation classes Maven Error

Tags: java, seam3, deltaspike

I followed the documentation to use @MessageBundle with Seam Solder 3.1.0 here :

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/solder-logging.html#typed-message-bundles

but a get en error at compile time when Maven try to compile generated annotation :

> [ERROR] error: Cannot read com.apps.web.messages package files, cause
>   : java.io.FileNotFoundException: com.apps.web.messages/WebMessages

When I check in target directory the file is generated correctly :

> target/generated-sources/annotations/com/apps/web/messages/WebMessages_$bundle.java

It seems that the maven plugins or the compiler can not find the interface WebMessages localized in src/main/java/com/apps/web/messages/ when he try to compile WebMessages_$bundle generated file.

Environnement:

Seam Solder 3.1.0.Final / 
Maven 3.0.3 / 
JDK 1.7 / 
JBoss AS 6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
  <compilerArgument>-AtranslationFilesPath=${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations</compilerArgument>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The compilerArgument solve the issue.